# Jenkins doesn't verify/review change on Gerrit

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I'm trying to configure a local installation of Jenkins to review uploaded changes on Gerrit. So far, I've gotten Jenkins to detect uploaded changes and build them (using Gerrit Trigger). However, while the build concludes successfully on Jenkins, it doesn't post any reviews on Gerrit, even though it is configured to do so. Interestingly, in Gerrit change history, I can see Jenkins having started a build:

```
Jenkins    Patch Set 1: Build Started http://localhost:8080/job/TestProject/70/
```

but that's it. No results are shown after this, like successful conclusion of the build etc. Since I can see the build started result, I'm assuming I've configured the review settings correctly, but something else is causing a hold up. I've checked in the Gerrit error_log file and it doesn't show any errors. What maybe the issue?

By the way I've been able to verify/review the code as jenkins using the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make code verification possible, you have to go through the following steps:

- Allow [label “Verified”](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html) on Gerrit server (also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229536/edit-project-config-in-a-gerrit-project) or [here](http://blog.bruin.sg/2013/04/how-to-edit-the-project-config-for-all-projects-in-gerrit/));
- Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060650/jenkins-gerrit-trigger-not-fetching-my-change-while-building) and make sure your job configured properly, because you will not build latest changesets instead;
- Give access to labels Code-Review and Verified in your Gerrit project for user Jenkins;

Comment: Thank you saver! I figured out the issue and managed to resolve it myself a few hours before you answered. :)

Comment: Any way through which I can override the rating given by jenkins gerrit.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding the 'Verified Label' to the Gerrit Server. The version of Gerrit I used (2.11.3) explicitly asks you to install the Verified Label, and the default option is set at No and as a result I didn't install it. I simply reinstalled my Gerrit, this time choosing Yes on Install Verified Label. If you're facing this issue, simply reinstall your Gerrit. If re-installation is not an option, read this:

> http://blog.bruin.sg/2013/04/how-to-edit-the-project-config-for-all-projects-in-gerrit/

Answer (score 0):

Some basic information can be found also in [Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger)

```
    Create the profile through in Gerrit web interface for your Jenkins    user, and set up a SSH key for that user.
    Gerrit web interface > Admin > Groups > Non-Interactive Users > Add your    jenkins user.
    Admin > Projects > ... > Access > Edit
    Reference: refs/*
    Read: ALLOW for Non-Interactive Users
    Reference: refs/heads/*
    Label Code-Review: -1, +1 for Non-Interactive Users
    Label Verified: -1, +1 for Non-Interactive Users
```